# Change the "like" destination dynamically?

Tags: facebook

Classic Like button code :

```
<div class="fb-like" style="position:relative;float:left;" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=1" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

it render the I Like Facebook button to the `http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=1` page. Now, suppose I'd like, due to some action on the page, change the destination to `http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=2` : how can I do it? I need to destroy and create again the button? I mean dynamically, without "refresh" the page (which will be easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to destroy the already initialized button and replace it with another one then call `FB.XFBML.parse()` which will reparse the XFBML and re-initialize the new button.

Comment: I just mean remove it from the DOM, assuming you have jQuery you'd use `$('.fb-like').remove();`.

Comment: You can specify the element `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));`

Comment: Not really http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840786/why-fb-xfbml-parse-doesnt-render-my-plugin

Comment: @markzzz Yes really https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/ what you are linking to is having a separate issue of not being able to render his initial widget due to a missing `fb-root`, while you are attempting to render something after the initial xfbml parsing has happened.

Comment: So you are able to answer to my other post? I don't have understand what you mean with fb-root parsing! Can you help me to understand that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use jquery?

```
$('.fb-like').attr("data-href", "http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=2");​
```

OR if you don't want to use jquery, assign an id to the like `div` and try this code (Assuming you've set the id to `fb-like`):

```
document.getElementById('fb-like').setAttribute('data-href','http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=2');
```

​

That will dynamically update your link.

Comment: Well mate, it doesnt works : http://jsfiddle.net/gVz3G/ . First whould be http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=1, than, after change the link, on http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=2. But it points every time at http://www.mywebsite.com/?IDL=1.