# Why FB.XFBML.parse() doesnt render my plugin?

Tags: jquery, facebook, xfbml

My [code](http://jsfiddle.net/82GT9/2/) :

```
<a id="render-me" href="javascript:void(0);">Render me</a>
<div id="social-facebook"></div>​

$('#render-me').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#social-facebook').html("<fb:like id='button-facebook' href='http://www.google.com' send='false' layout='button_count' width='450' show_faces='false'></fb:like>");
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('button-facebook'));    
});
```

I click, but the button is not rendered. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to specify a node already in DOM.
So, you can't use:

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('button-facebook'));
```

use instead:

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('social-facebook'));
```

and it will work fine ;)

Comment: Something changed since 2012 - and when doing this just now I had to parse the parent element - something like this `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('social-facebook')?.parentElement);`

Comment: Another tip is to enable (temporarily!) the debug version of the SDK and look in the console for messages. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/advanced-setup/

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this markup

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

in bottom of page and make sure you are added FB script. 
Please have a look the image

[image]

Please follow these steps you will able to solve you problem.

For more info please go through this link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Nothing change man! In fact I add the plugins after the "load/ready", so also if I put fb-root at the bottom nothing change! Tried with that code..nothing : in a click handler it doesnt render...

Comment: That's funny : if I wrote only `FB.XFBML.parse();` it works :O

Comment: "*That's funny : if I wrote only FB.XFBML.parse(); it works :O*" -- this is because you are re-parsing the ENTIRE page (every plugin). Not just the section you are aiming for.