# How to insert Facebook login button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I'd like to add a Facebook login button to my HTML page using Javascript:

```
var button = document.createElement("fb:login-button");
button.size = "xlarge";
parent.appendChild(button);
```

The button appears, and non Facebook-specific attributes like `id` and `lang` can be added succesfully.  However, adding the size attribute has no effect.

Also, if I try to add *any* attribute using `button.createAttribute()`, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #`<HTMLUnknownElement>` has no method 'createAttribute'

Why is Facebook's login button not recognized as a valid HTML element, even though it appears on the page?  What is the correct way to insert a Facebook login button using Javascript and change its size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to dynamically render these social plugins. Once you have the SDK initialized, you can manipulate your page all you want, then all you'll have to do is make a call to the `FB.XFBML.parse()` function, and the tags will be shown correctly.

You can even call the function on a specific element for more control:

```
FB.XFBML.parse( document.getElementById( 'some-element' ) );
// or with jQuery
FB.XFBML.parse( $( "#some-element" )[0] )
```

You also should try to append the markup manually as a string:

```
element.innerHTML += '<fb:login-button id="some-element" size="xlarge"/>'; 
FB.XFBML.parse( document.getElementById( 'some-element' ) );
```

---

Here's the overview from the [relevant documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/):

> This function **parses and renders XFBML markup in a document on the
>   fly**. This could be used if you send XFBML from your server via ajax
>   and want to render it client side. XFBML enables you to incorporate
>   FBML into your websites and IFrame applications.
>
> You can parse the following XFBML tags with this method:
>
> - fb:activity
> - fb:comments
> - fb:friendpile
> - fb:like
> - fb:like-box
> - **fb:login-button** <-------------- <sup>*WOOHOO!*</sup>
> - fb:name
> - fb:profile-pic
> - fb:recommendations

Comment: If I call this function on the whole document (no arguments) or the parent node, I get two login buttons, both working, both the normal size.  If I call it on the button itself, nothing happens, because the element it's called on [has to be in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13553768/1397061).

Comment: So then just call the parse function after `appendChild()`. Not sure why two plugins are appearing... If you are triggering the parse "manually", check that `xfbml` is set to false (in the JS SDK) - that might be what's parsing the tags twice.

Comment: I am calling it after `appendChild()`, and as you predicted, the duplication goes away when `xfbml` is set to false.  However, this still doesn't make the button the correct size. :(

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by manually writing the HTML: `parent.innerHTML += '<fb:login-button id="login" size="xlarge"/>'; FB.XFBML.parse(content);`.  This almost makes sense: you want to create raw text for the XFBML parser, rather than extending the DOM tree.  Feel free to edit your answer to include the working code.

Comment: you need to call FB.XFBML.parse() on the parent element of the <fb:* ...> element